# Are there any inherent shortcomings in this schema?

Tags: mysql, schema

[image: Events Registration Schema Diagram]

This is derived from the SQL generated by sqldbm.com that I simplified because it wasn't generating foreign keys correctly and it seems to me that there's no need to pull in every foreign key from the parent anyway (perhaps I'm mistaken!) [image: sqldbm.com schema diagram]

1. Is there significant value in pulling in every foreign key from the parent and making them part of the child's primary key? Is there a way to automate setting these additional keys? (I.e. a ticket row being a child of an event row which is a child of a location row and the ticket row also includes location_id and needing to make sure that gets set correctly.)
2. Does anyone see anything in the upper schema diagram that might shoot me in the foot down the road? Not pictured but desired is an additional many-to-many mapping to event questionnaire responses also attached to a ticket (i.e. a registrant providing answers to experience levels in a sport discipline, gear questions, etc as part of their ticket purchase). I am already planning on removing the multiple locations for costs and having option value be the only place cost is found and always having an option value supplied for each event.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 1) "Is there significant value in pulling in every foreign key from the parent and making them part of the child's primary key?" ? Pick two tables and ask the question why should/shouldn't this foreign key relationship exist.

Comment: See the difference between the top diagram and the bottom. the sqldbm design tool wanted to pull in every key from the parent and I had to manually edit them out. I'm wondering if there's a reason the tool was written to have that default behavior, is there any value in pulling in all keys, other than being able to skip intermediate joins and queries to walk up the tree of relations?

Comment: I _guessed_ that the blue PK-FK lines were indicating an FK to some other table, not that this was part of the current PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's very difficult to just cast one's eye over a schema and say, "Yep that's great" or "Yes, that's going to work".

Schema and system design is an [iterative process](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) - you start with a few ideas, implement them and test to see how it's working. Then you rejig the bits that aren't working and see - now the rejigging will (in all likelihood) break some bits that were working previously and that you hadn't changed - so you tweak again, and hopefully you asymptotically approach (nirvana...) a decent working app.

I can only advise you to

- visit databaseanswers.org - check out [databaseanswers](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) - there's lots of links related to tickets and events, and
- check out your search engine of choice for "open source reservation systems" (or similar) and download some systems and check out their schemas.

Sorry not to be able to be of more help, but it's analagous to asking "I'm thinking about writing a book, here are the chapter titles, will it be good?".

Start out your system and if you have more specific questions, come back here and ask them - p.s. welcome to the forum.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't expecting some answer as to the longevity, mostly technical correctness. My first time really working to relate tables and in particular my first time with many-to-many. Definitely checking out that link.

Comment: A first look seems to suggest to me that it **looks** OK. Basically, it's a bit like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) - and anyone who says that 95% of software development doesn't work like that is either an academic or works for Microsoft :-)

Comment: It's funny. I'm a lot more loose with development iterations for actual work than I am personal projects. But I have a lot more experience with control systems, I/O, and automation than with database design.

Comment: Well, best of luck with the project - can't really add any more - just hope you found my answer even a little helpful.

Comment: Accepting for that awesome link to databaseanswers' models

Answer (score 1):

A few specifics:

- Don't use `DOUBLE` for money; use `DECIMAL(m,n)`
- Consider using shorter versions of `INT` and consider `UNSIGNED`.
- The diagrams don't show whether you have *composite* indexes or single-column indexes.
- Don't expect to finalize a schema before having the `SELECTs` at least sketched out.
- I see a couple of `CHAR` columns -- are they yes/no flags?
- Good:  I'm glad you did not normalize city and state.
- For many:many performance tips, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score -1):

Rick is right - for the money type, use DECIMAL or more precisely DECIMAL(10,2), most of the time it will suffice. You can also use the prefix tb_ for table names - this can make your code easier for you to maintain.

[image: tickets-events-database-schema]

Comment: Why prefix table names? A query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES will list all your tables. And if you need to change the name of a table and insert a view with the old name you'll then need to change code that depends on the table's name -- or else you'll have a view starting with "tb_". Don't do it.

Comment: Other than that, your answer adds nothing to Rick's.

Comment: Apart from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, there is also a source code (PHP, JAVA etc.) and sometimes it is worth using prefixes, it is easier to distinguish the table ticket from variable ticket. In addition, you can give different prefixes depending on the type of table, for example, give dictionary tables "dict_", tables with settings give "par_" and names of tables with logs start with "log_". Thanks to the use of a prefix, we gain an additional benefit - tables of the same type will be presented next to each other in IDE tools.

Comment: That’s a different type of prefix then just prefixing all tables with tb_.