# Normalization Problem for drugstores information

Tags: database-design, performance, optimization, normalization

I want to capture all data about 10000 drug stores in my country.

I design as follows:

```
Drugstore main info (uniqueid, hi_number, drugstorename, drugstoretype, drugstorerelateuniversity, servicetype, workinghours, locationcity)

Drugstore details info (uniqueid, Address, Postalcode, Tell, GPSinfo, Area)

Drugstore Holder Detail (uniqueid, dh_type, Name, Family, int_code, city, address, tellو licensenumber, Quota)

Drugstore  Pharmacy technician (uniqueid, teclicense, expiredate, name, family, tell, city, wokr_time)
```

each Pharmacy technician can work on 1 or more pharmacy, and each drugstore holder can hold 1 or more pharmacy, and each drugstore main info has one drugstore detail info.

Is our schema good for implementation in DB? or it need some normalization?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206403/34007) - it's virtually impossible to look at a schema and say whether it's going to be good or bad for a given job - you'll have to try it out and see - do a bit of prototyping, correct problems (which will cause other problems) and so on - software design and implementation is an iterative process - start off and then get back to us here if you have any **particular specific** problems!

Answer (score 1):

If there's a 1-to-1 match between `drugstoreMain` and `drugstoreDetail` (that I, every `drugstoreMain` row has one and only one matching `drugstoreDetail` row), then it seems like the logical table would simply be `drugstore`, with all the columns in one table.

There are potential reasons to split it up. In particular, if there's a set of columns that will be rarely referenced, and another set that will be frequently referenced, then it could improve performance to separate out the rarely-referenced columns. However, with proper indexing and good specification of columns needed (avoid `SELECT *`), performance may be about as good with one table as two.

Also, of course, I may have misunderstood, and you may have a requirement to have a main and a detail table. Still, it's good to think these things through.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

You are going to need some data types in there.

the drugstore_main is larger than the drugstore_details table, which could make things slow down the road.

How are you getting the data? That will play a large role in how you want to structure your database. It might be easier to build your database to reflect the flat files you're using to populate it.

Oh, and save yourself a lot of trouble by using integer ID's, don't use newid().

Comment: What do u mean by "How are you getting the data?" and what do u mean by dont use newid()?

Comment: drugstore_main is larger than the drugstore_details table. how I can solve it?

Comment: Are you planning to fill it all out from scratch yourself? To me, that sounds like a lot of work. It's possible that nobody has a list of pharmacies in your country, but probably someone has something. Try and get hold of it. See if you can get a data set to start with, and build your database around it.

Comment: James I have a data set. I do this design from this data set. but how I can get good table?

Comment: I'd reduce drugstore_main to the first four columns, then shift the rest to another table. Newid() is a function that generates a unique 32 charachter guid. It's sort of useful sometimes, but it's almost better to use integers in your id fields.

Comment: Can you post a few rows from your data set?

Comment: This dataset is not normalize, why you need these rows?

Comment: It's not a matter of need. I'd work on getting the data normalized first. You can always change the DB schema as you go along.

Comment: I can add multiple row, but I'm sure that no need because that table structure is very bad. I need to design it at first as my proposed in question

Comment: Ahh, ok. What you've got is probably good enough to start. Don't be afraid to change it later on, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think about adding a column and a  foreign key for the pharmacy tech table to make sure only valid drug store ID's can be assigned to the tech.

Comment: uniqueid tell us a guarantee that technician add to a defined drugstore with uniqueid, is'nt it?

Comment: Didn't catch that before. I'm used to seeing columns like this across tables with a unique name in each table.

Comment: So my table is good? you means?

Comment: it's something you need to test yourself. You can make arguments for and against over-normalization all day long but i've seen queries with a half a dozen joins take 30 seconds or longer to run and retrieve a few dozen rows.    The reason for my original comment was that i've seen wrong data entered into a database and it creates all kinds of issues. Forcing people to enter clean data the first time will avoid problems later on.